# entity framework telling the context an entity has been updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a scenario where I have an image property that is part of a product entity.

When allowing a user to Edit this product via MVC3 screen, the image property is displayed as follows:

```
<div class="editor-label">Image</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @if (Model.ProductItem.ImageData == null)
        {
        @:None
        }
        else
        {
            <img alt="Product Image" width="125" height="125" 
            src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new { Model.ProductItem.ProductId     })" />
        }
    </div>

    <div>Upload new image: <input type="file" name="Image" /></div>
```

To edit the current image the user essentially selects a new one via the upload. This means that the current ImageData property is null and the model state is invalid. The new image is past back in the post so I set this to the ImageData property and clear the model validation error.

I then save the 'changes' via the context.savechanges() method, however the context doesn't think there are any changes to this particular entity. To get round this I have done the following when on Edit:

```
      if (context.Products.Local.Count() == 0)
            {
                Product procurr = context.Products
                    .Where(p => p.ProductId == product.ProductId)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                context.Entry(procurr).CurrentValues.SetValues(product);    
            }
```

Essentially I am forcing an update on the item in the list of products that I want to updqate (procurr is the item in the list and product is the new edited values I want to save)

My questions would be (A) Is this the best way to do this in terms of using the context, and (B) Is there a better way to do this in the UI ie someway of tying together the old and new image so as the model automatically picks up the changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done looks correct.

The basic idea is that when you get data from the server and return it to the browser, the EF context that you are using gets closed.

When the reply comes back from the browser you need to connect the data with the row that you are trying to update.

Reading the row based on the id, updating the relevant fields and then running save changes, is a good approach.